# Remote server returned an error 500 - Error while calling a soap webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, soap-client

I am trying to call a webservice by POST method. Input xml is rpc/literal soap message.

```
    Dim myRequest As Net.HttpWebRequest
    Dim objResponse As Net.HttpWebResponse
    Dim result As String
    Dim data As Byte()
    Dim newStream As System.IO.Stream

    Dim strURL As String = "https://abxxxx"
    strXml.Load("D:\MyXml.xml")

    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strXml.InnerXml)
    myRequest = WebRequest.Create(strURL)
    myRequest.Method = "POST"
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length
    myRequest.Timeout = 125000
    newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    newStream.Close()
    objResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()
    Dim sr As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
    strOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
    'Close connections
    sr.Close()
    objResponse.Close()
```

Code throws an exception of "Remote server returned an error : 500" on the line     `objResponse = myRequest.GetResponse()`

This is the actual soap response from web service:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CONTACT"). Expected elements are (none) </faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is working perfectly when I add a reference to this web service using visual studio (proxy class) but I do not need to use this method.

Please suggest if I am missing something!

Comment: Do not use WebRequest/WebResponse. Se "[How to Consume a Web Service](https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0 and need to call this web service from server side code.

Comment: So use "Add Web Reference". Also, .NET 2.0 is what? A decade old? You must not have any competitors.

Comment: I already tried web reference and that is working but I have not to use web reference as my project has some genric components for this task. Code is written there already.

Comment: The exception you're getting means the server doesn't like what you're sending. Based on the fault it sent back, it doesn't like your `<CONTACT>` element.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely and 101% correct. Wsdl analysis suggested I need to send some nodes as text in my input. I finally figured it out after spending many hours on research. Wish you could provide this information a bit earlier :) but anyway thanks a lot for your kind assistance.

Comment: Whoever is preventing you from using "Add Web Reference", remind them that it "just worked". Also tell them it's past time they started using a later version of .NET. .NET 3.5 is just .NET 2.0 SP2 with some new libraries - it's unlikely to break anything.

Comment: Ok. I will certainly raise this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on analysing and research of the wsdl of my service, I was able to find the fix for this issue.

We need to use CDATA (ie constant data) for all those xml nodes which are not direct exposed in WSDL and thus this tag should be sent as text to the service. This tag was under a parent tag which was defined in wsdl. I applied CDATA to send these information in my soap xml.

```
<PARENT><![CDATA[<CONTACT>abcd </CONTEXT>]]></PARENT>
```

I found some useful information about the error 500 - Remote server returned an error - This error is reproduced from  service and there could be many reasons behind this. To get the exact reason for the error we require actual response from the service as fault code and fault string.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body>
<soap:Fault>
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CONTACT"). Expected elements are (none) </faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

`<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>` - Issue is from client ie client input.

```
<faultstring>Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CONTACT"). Expected elements are (none) </faultstring>
```

This error suggests that we are passing blank uri for the element `<CONTACT>`. uri here represents the namespace of the `<CONTACT>` tag which should be available in the service wsdl of the corresponding operation. This element is referred here as LOCAL and as service did not have information about this tag in wsdl, it was trying to find the  namespace for this element.

Hope this could help many more people facing this same problem.